# How do I make services available outside of constructor in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have the following problem. When I have a class in ionic with angular I can access angular services in the constructor after injecting them:

```
export class HomeController {
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$state'
    ];

    constructor(
       public $scope : any,
       public $state : any
    ) {
        this.$state.go('test');
        this.$scope.changeController = this.changeController;
    }

    changeController() {
        console.log("change controller");
    };
}
```

However when I change it to the change controller function, it doesn't work

```
export class HomeController {
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$state'
    ];

    constructor(
       public $scope : any,
       public $state : any
    ) {
        this.$scope.changeController = this.changeController;
    }

    changeController() {
        console.log("change controller");
        this.$state.go('test'); // Fails here
    };
}
```

This is the error:

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$state.go')

What can I do?

On top of that, is it correct add the changeController function to the scope or is there an easier method to make it available to a template?

Thx in advance

Comment: Maybe `this` is what is undefined. Have you tried `changeController() => {...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the value of `this` is incorrect which is a very common issue due to misunderstanding of ES6 classes. Try using lambda to have lexical scoping:

```
  changeController = () => {
    console.log("change controller");
    this.$state.go('test'); // Fails here
  };
```